# Same listener for list and button

Tags: android, onclick

In my application pressing a list row or a button means executing the same commands. My problem is that the list and the button have different listeners (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener vs. View.OnClickListener). How can I add the code for the 2 views (as a listener) without having duplicate code.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to write a wrapper class to both Button and List, and have a common listener.... and use them in you project.. 
but if you are not ready to take this pain, the easiest way is as Octavian told, put the logic in a method, and call it from both the places :)

Comment: Could you, please, be more specific with the wrapper class?

Comment: yes, Write a class as MyButton which extends Button and MyList which extends List and let them impliment a interface called MyInterface which has a method called as widgetTaped (...) now in both MyList and MyList when their respective click listners are called, call the widgetTaped() method. There are many other ways to do it too... please explore

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I created a listener which implements the list listener and the view's listener, and that has a method called in both of the listeners methods.

Comment: good going.. Please share the code... that will help others too :)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I add the code for the 2 views (as a listener) without having duplicate code.

Implement the work logic in a method and just call that method from your listeners.

Comment: I know that, but using a static method isn't my first choice. I was wondering if I could use one listener for the 2 cases.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to have one overall listener. Also who says it has to be a static method? I haven't said that.

Comment: it won't be a static method, (one up for Octavian) ... one addition, I used a boolean variable to determine the source of my method call... Thanx again Octavian !

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
public class SelectRecipeListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, 
                                    View.OnClickListener{
private Context currentContext;
private boolean storeAsLastViewed;

public SelectRecipeListener(Context context, boolean store) {
    currentContext = context;
    storeAsLastViewed = store;
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    execute((String) view.getTag());
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    execute((String) v.getTag());
}

private void execute(String id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(currentContext, RecipeTabHost.class);
    intent.putExtra(currentContext.getResources().getString(
            R.string.recipe_id_transition_key), id);
    intent.putExtra(currentContext.getResources().getString(
            R.string.last_recipe_id_storing_key), storeAsLastViewed);
    currentContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

}